# CSV contents being deleted without me asking it to and not being able to write to it

Tags: python, csv

I am currently creating a program that can allow a user to order products using a GTIN code or restocking the products so that the stock is up. However, I am having some issues I have not have had before with this.

### 1. Deletion of CSV contents

Firstly, I try to write to my CSV file in both `quantityQuestion` and `restockAction` - but when I run the program the contents of the CSV are completely deleted.

### 2. Unable to write to a specific row

Secondly, I want to update the stock following an order in `quantityQuestion`. I have written `row[2] = str(int(row[2]) - int(quantity))` so that the quantity is essentially removed from itself. I feel as if this problem is related to the first problem.

### 3. Code

Code is as follows:

```
import csv
import sys

global totalPrice
totalPrice = 0

addItem = ""
gtinNum = ""
quantity = 0
restart = ""
price = 0

receipt = open("receipt.txt", "w+")
restockTxt = open("restock.txt", "w+")

def restart():
    restart = input("Would you like to restart? Y/N")

    if restart.lower() == "y":
        actionQ()
    else:
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit()

def priceSub(): #Defining the restart subprogram
    priceQ = input("Would you like to add an item? Y/N") #Asks the user if they would like to add an item.
    global totalPrice #Declaring totalPrice and making it global.
    totalPrice = int(price) + totalPrice #Setting totalPrice to add the variable price to itself.

    if priceQ.lower() == "y": #If statement that checks to see if the user has entered a "y".
        gtinQuestion() #If it is true, it will start the gtinQuestion subprogram.
    else: #Anything other than a "y" will do the following commands.
        global receiptCont #Declaring the receipt content as a global variable.
        receiptCont = receipt.read() #Reads the receipt.
        receipt.close() #Closes the file.
        print(receiptCont) #Prints the content of the receipt.
        print("Total Price: " + "%.2f" % round(totalPrice, 2)) #Prints the totalPrice variable rounded to two decimal places.
        restart()

def quantityQuestion(): #Defining the subprogram for the quantity.
    quantity = input("How much would you like?") #Asks the user how much of the item they would like.
    if quantity.isdigit() == False: #If statement to check whether or not the user has entered an integer or not.
        quantityQuestion() #If they have not entered an integer, it will ask the question again.
    global price #Declaring the variable price as a global variable.
    price = "" #Setting price to an empty string.

    file2 = open("ChocolateCSV2.csv", "r")
    file2w = open("ChocolateCSV2.csv", "w", newline="")
    reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter = ",")
    csvList = list(reader)

    for row in reader: #Loop that seperates each row in the CSV
        if str(gtinNum) in row: #If statement to check if the GTIN given by the user is in the CSV.
            receipt.write(str(row) + "\n") #If it is in one of the CSV rows, it will write the row to the text file.
            receipt.write(str("- Quantity: " + quantity + "\n")) #It also writes the quantity given by the user.
            price = float(row[2]) * int(quantity) #The price is the price given by the CSV file multiplied by the quantity.
            receipt.write("- Price: " + str("%.2f" % round(price, 2)) + "\n") #The final price (after the multiplication) is written to the text file also.
            row[2] = str(int(row[2]) - int(quantity))
            writeCSV = csv.writer(file2w)
            writeCSV.writerow(row)
            file2w.close()
            priceSub() #Starts the restart subprogram.
            break #Breaks the loop.
    else:
            print("The code entered could not be found - Please re-enter") #If it is not in the CSV it will print this error message.
            gtinQuestion() #Starts the gtinQuestion subprogram.

def gtinQuestion(): #Defining the gtinQuestion subprogram.
    global gtinNum #Declaring the gtinNum variable as global.
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:") #Setting that variable to the initial question.

    if gtinNum.isdigit() == False or len(gtinNum) != 8: #If the code given is not an integer or is not 8 digits long...
        print("Please re-enter your GTIN-8 code - Reason: Invalid Code") #It will print this error message and ask the question again.
        gtinQuestion()
    elif gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8: #If it is an integer and is 8 digits long...
        quantityQuestion() #It will start the quantityQuestion subprogram.

def restockAction():
    reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter = ",")
    csvList = list(reader)
    global file2w
    file2w = open("ChocolateCSV2.csv", "w")
    file2 = open("ChocolateCSV2.csv", "r")

    for row in csvList:
        stDiff = float(row[5]) - float(row[3])
        if float(row[3]) <= float(row[4]):
            restockTxt.write(row[0]+" | "+row[1]+" | "+"Stock Replenished: "+(str(stDiff)+"\n"))
            restockTxt.close()
            row[3] = row[5]
            writeCSV = csv.writer(file2w)
            writeCSV.writerows(csvList)
            file2w.close()
    else:
            restockTxt.write("No (other) stock needs to be replenished.")
            restockTxt.close()
            restockRead = open("restock.txt", "r")
            print(restockRead.read())
            restart()

def actionQ():
    restock = input("What action would you like to perform?:\n Restock (Enter 1)\n Order (Enter 2)")

    if restock == "1" or restock == "restock":
        print("Restock Action Requested...")
        restockAction()
    elif restock == "2" or restock == "order":
        print("Ordering action Requested...")
        gtinQuestion()
    else:
        actionQ()

actionQ()
```

Thanks in advance - any help is welcome

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode erases its previous contents.

Comment: @JohnGordon Is this the case with a CSV? If so, how can I counter it?

Comment: It's the case with any file.  If you want to open it for writing and retain the existing contents, use `a` mode instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you. Quick question, when I want to write to a specific cell it will overwrite the cell right?

Comment: Yes -- *if* you're positioned at the right spot in the file *and* you're writing the exact same number of bytes.  If you just open the file in `a` mode and start writing willy-nilly, the new information will be appended onto the end of the file.

Comment: @JohnGordon How could I go about overwriting the whole CSV? I tried to write, like you said, willy-nilly and it appended it to the end.

Comment: Updating a file with new information in the middle is tricky business.  It's probably a lot easier to create a new file and then rename it to the old filename when you're done.

Comment: Think of the CSV files as transactional logs. Write in all of the transactions as they occur and wherever you are sending these logs they should process them all. You will end up with the correct result. Trying to perform updates in CSV files is just an attempt to make your life as difficult as possible.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Ah, I know what you mean. My life is as difficult as it is! Thankfully, John has helped me greatly with this.

Comment: You could read the contents of the file into a variable, and then overwrite the existing file with the updated contents...